# ATL COM 32-bit dll to 64-bit non-COM dll

Tags: c++, com, 64-bit, atl

I have a 32-bit dll library project written in C++ ATL COM. How do you convert a ATL COM project to pure C++ non-COM 64-bit? I believe ATL COM, or COM, doesn't support 64-bit.

Are there any instructions/guidelines on how to strip away the ATL COM part of such a project and replace it with managed or unmanaged C++, so it's compile able to 64-bit?

Best Regards,
Johan

Comment: "I believe ATL COM, or COM, doesn't support COM" is a confusing statement even in the land of COM.

Comment: @AlexK. COM land never stops surprising me, so why not? :-) Just kidding. It was meant to be ATL COM doesn't support 64-bit.

Comment: It is not a sensible question.  An ATL project most definitely supports COM, the reason for being for ATL.  Stripping it can't work, the library becomes unusable unless it is *completely* redesigned.  Simply changing the project's Platform selection from Win32 to x64 is the right way.  If that produces a build error then you forgot to mention it.

Comment: @HansPassant Forgive me for the typo and being unclear. I want to convert the project to 64-bit and therefore strip ATL away, so as to make it a non-COM 64bit dll.

Comment: "ATL COM and COM" do support 64-bit. But it's impossible to answer the "how to strip away the ATL COM part", this is far too broad a question. Plus, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @SimonMourier I thought ATL COM was 32-bit only.

Comment: It is possible to create a 64-bit ATL control, but Visual Studio IDE is a 32-bit process so you can not register a 64-bit ATL control in the toolbox. For example, the  problem may be "How to use 64-bit ATL control in WinForms or WPF application development" ?