# ATL::CComContainedObject<contained>: C2259 Cannot instantiate abstract class

Tags: c++, com, 64-bit, atl

I have an ATL COM project which I want to port to 64 bit.

After changing the platform to x64 and starting the build I get among other errors the following

`ATL::CComContainedObject<contained>: C2259 Cannot instantiate abstract class` in atlcom.h

I also get this error

`C2338 CAtlDllModuleT<T> must be used with either _WINDLL or _USRDLL`
in atlbase.h

It compiles fine on 32bit. Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this? 
I have found this similar question and answer, but I can't understand how to apply it in my case.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d6144eaa-fa37-4133-87a0-75a06633209b/compiling-64bit-results-in-a-2259-cannot-instantiate-abstract-class?forum=vclanguage

I have posted a similar broader question earlier:

[ATL COM 32-bit dll to 64-bit non-COM dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52702542/atl-com-32-bit-dll-to-64-bit-non-com-dll)

Comment: ATL is compatible with 64-bit, but it does not mean you can take any existing (old?) project and hope it will build Win64 w/o a problem. The initial error is very generic, it just mean there's a problem between definition and implementation (it can be many things like argument size, attributes, pointers, etc..). You probably have more information in the detailed output on the class/method, etc. It's difficult to help w/o more details. Another solution is start a new project with the new VS 2017 templates, and add your files one by one (more work but you'll know what your doing)

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you for your comment. It seems as I did a very newbie mistake. I didn't take time to copy the settings from the 32bit profile to the 64bit. A lot of important parameters were not set right. After updating the 64bit profile it builds without problem. Now remains to test if the 64-bit dll works as intended.

Comment: You should answer yourself then

Answer (score 0):

As in comments above, the root of the problem was in the settings of the Visual studio 64bit project file. A lot of important parameters were not set right. After updating the 64bit profile according to the 32bit profile it built without errors.